# Guard fail : "Error: exit code 1" (Spork and TestUnit)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tdd, guard, spork

I'm new to TDD on Rails and I want the right tools. TestUnit+Spork+Guard seems perfect to me, but I can't make it work. The setup seems right, but when I launch Guard, this happens :

```
Ruff% guard --debug
16:08:59 - DEBUG - Command execution: which notify-send
16:08:59 - DEBUG - Command execution: emacsclient --eval '1' 2> /dev/null || echo 'N/A'
16:08:59 - INFO - Guard is using NotifySend to send notifications.
16:08:59 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
16:08:59 - DEBUG - Command execution: hash stty
16:08:59 - DEBUG - Guard starts all plugins
16:08:59 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::Spork
16:08:59 - DEBUG - Command execution: ps aux | grep -v guard | awk '/spork/&&!/awk/{print $2;}'
16:08:59 - DEBUG - Killing Spork servers with PID: 
16:08:59 - INFO - Starting Spork for Test::Unit
16:08:59 - DEBUG - guard-spork command execution: ["exec", "spork", "testunit", "-p", "8988"]
Using TestUnit, Rails
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8988!
16:09:05 - INFO - Spork server for Test::Unit successfully started
16:09:05 - DEBUG - Command execution: notify-send Spork Test::Unit successfully started -t 3000 -h int:transient:1 -i /home/simplonco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/guard-2.3.0/images/success.png -u low

16:09:05 - DEBUG - Hook :start_end executed for Guard::Spork
16:09:05 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::Test
16:09:05 - INFO - Guard::Test 2.0.4 is running, with Test::Unit 2.5.5!
16:09:05 - INFO - Running all tests
16:09:05 - INFO - Using testdrb to run the tests
16:09:05 - DEBUG - Command execution: testdrb -I"lib:test" 
Running tests with args ["-Ilib:test"]...
Usage: testrb [options] tests...
Error: exit code 1
Done.
```

"Error: exit code 1" is making me crazy, Guard won't launch the tests. I found nobody with the same problem.

When I modify a file, Guard recognize it and launch himself. Then this happens :

```
10:51:42 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_modifications_end executed for Guard::Test
10:51:42 - DEBUG - Start interactor
10:58:06 - DEBUG - Stop interactor
10:58:06 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_modifications_begin executed for Guard::Test
10:58:06 - INFO - Running: test/models/user_test.rb
10:58:06 - DEBUG - Command execution: testdrb -I"lib:test" 
Running tests with args ["-Ilib:test"]...
Usage: testrb [options] tests...
Error: exit code 1
Done.
```

I spend a lot of time on guard's documentation, can't find anything. Bundle exec guard don't work better. I tried to make a new app from scratch : "Error: exit code 1" again.

My Guardfile :

```
guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, 
           :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do


watch('Gemfile')
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end

guard :test, drb: true do
  watch(%r{^test/.+_test\.rb$})
  watch('test/test_helper.rb')  { 'test' }

  # Non-rails
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "test/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }

  # Rails 4
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb})                               { |m| "test/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/application_controller\.rb}) { 'test/controllers' }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_controller\.rb})        { |m| "test/integration/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)_mailer/.+})                   { |m| "test/mailers/#{m[1]}_mailer_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb})                               { |m| "test/lib/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
end
```

The test group of my gemfile :

```
group :test do
    gem 'turn'
    gem 'guard-test'
    gem 'guard-livereload'
    gem 'guard-spork' 
    gem 'spork-rails'
    gem 'spork-testunit'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [spork-testunit](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork-testunit) I see that the expected usage is

```
testdrb -Itest test/your_test.rb
```

whereas Guard executes

```
testdrb -I"lib:test"
```

Comparing those two, I see that the Guard command lacks the path to the tests, this is why Spork complains:

```
Usage: testrb [options] tests...
Error: exit code 1
```

This looks to me like you have a Guard configuration or a project structure/test naming issue, but it's hard to tell without seeing your `Guardfile` and know something about your test files.

In general Guard::Test [looks at your test path](https://github.com/guard/guard-test/blob/master/lib/guard/test.rb#L35) that is configured with the `test_path` option and is `test` by default. It then [tries to find your test files by a specific pattern](https://github.com/guard/guard-test/blob/master/lib/guard/test/inspector.rb#L53-L54), which are then passed to the command execution. This is of course only true if you run all tests.

The patterns are:

```
Dir[File.join(path, '**', 'test_*.rb')] +
Dir[File.join(path, '**', '*_test{s,}.rb')]
```

So depending on your test file naming pattern, you can verify it in the rails console:

```
rails c
[1] pry(main)> Dir[File.join('test', '**', '*_test{s,}.rb')]
=> []
```

Here it fails for me, since I use RSpec, but it should return a list of all you test files if everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forget to specify an important fact : when I change a file (test file or tested file), guard see it and launch itself. But it don't launch the test, it end with "exit code 1". 

So Guard know the path for the test. The file is named user_test.rb, so "Dir[File.join('test', '**', '*_test{s,}.rb')]" works fine. 

I keep searching, and I'm adding my guardfile to my question.

Comment: Just to retract myself : guard know where to find test files when I modifify them, not when I try to launch them. I think you're right about the path problem, just need to understand it better.

Comment: I'd use a debugger and see what's going on in the Inspector class of guard-test, it looks like it strips all test files away.